# Can not Execute JavaScript command using Selenium WebDriver in C#

Tags: javascript, c#, selenium-chromedriver

I can not execute js command using selenium web driver. for example, I used 3 ways for this URL but all of them return null.

```
                    web.FindElementByJs("StackExchange.init.length");

                    IJavaScriptExecutor js = (IJavaScriptExecutor)web;
                    string title = (string)js.ExecuteScript("StackExchange.init.length");

                    web.ExecuteJavaScript("StackExchange.init.length");
```

Answer (score 0):

I get it!
For an object, I should use 'window'.

```
IJavaScriptExecutor js = (IJavaScriptExecutor)web;
string title = (string)js.ExecuteScript("return window.StackExchange.init.length");
```